# Interface applications in different languages

Tags: node.js, sockets, interface, elixir

For some Languages there are some libraries, my concern is limited, **what should I do for Elixir and NodeJS**?(Cannot find a reputed library for this purpose)

However, additional insight on how to communicate with applications in different languages is appreciated. I have tried communicating between different applications using **Socket connections, JSON, and other similar methods**. Suppose when making a PC game do developers still use Socket, JSON and similar methods, if not then how do they serve the purpose of communicating with applications in different languages?

Note: I am new to this AMA, from what I have read, I think my question adheres to standards, if not then I will edit and trim unwanted content.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ports for communicating with other programs.

The [official docs](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html) are the best reference:

> Ports provide the basic mechanism for communication with the external world, from Erlang's point of view. They provide a byte-oriented interface to an external program. When a port has been created, Erlang can communicate with it by sending and receiving lists of bytes, including binaries.

The [Elixir documentation on ports](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html) provides this as a simple example:

```
iex> port = Port.open({:spawn, "cat"}, [:binary])
iex> send port, {self(), {:command, "hello"}}
iex> send port, {self(), {:command, "world"}}
iex> flush()
{#Port<0.1444>, {:data, "hello"}}
{#Port<0.1444>, {:data, "world"}}
iex> send port, {self(), :close}
:ok
iex> flush()
{#Port<0.1464>, :closed}
:ok
```

If you are calling a Python or Ruby program, you may want to investigate [ErlPort](https://github.com/hdima/erlport). I have a project right now which uses ports to talk to both Python and Node for scripting purposes. We use ErlPort for Python, and just the raw `Port` API for the Node scripts.